# Extract entities from sentences

Tags: python, performance, natural-language-processing

I have a function that extracts basic parts-of-speech words (NN,NNP,JJ,VBS etc.) from about 2000 sentences. I want to understand if there is a way to optimize so I can bring down the execution time (from about 12 secs right now to single digits) if possible.

```
import re, nltk, html

def extract_entities(text_list):

    entities=set()

    for sentence in text_list:
        try:

            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
            [entities.add(word.lower()) for word,pos in tagged
                 if pos in ['NN','NNP','NNS','NNPS','JJ','VBS','VBN','VBG','VBD']]

        except Exception as e:
            print('stage 1',e)

    return entities
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few possible improvements:

1. Use a `set` for the positions you want and make it a constant. (This will give you a small speed-boost, because `in` is O(n) for lists, but O(1) for sets.)
2. Don't use a list-comprehension with side-effects for a loop.
3. Follow Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Specifically:

   a) Don't do multiple imports

   b) Put spaces around your operators

   c) Put a space after a comma in an argument list
4. Limit the scope of your `try..except`

With these fixes, here is the final code, as I would write it:

```
import re
import nltk
import html

POSITIONS = {'NN','NNP','NNS','NNPS','JJ','VBS','VBN','VBG','VBD'}

def extract_entities(text_list):
    entities = set()
    for sentence in text_list:
        try:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        except Exception as e:
            print('stage 1', e)
            continue
        for word, pos in tagged:
            if pos in POSITIONS:
                entities.add(word.lower())
    return entities
```

Comment: Thanks @Graipher. I followed your suggestion but it did not give me any performance benefit. I wanted to get an opinion as to if it possible to introduce ctypes that can give some performance boost?

Comment: @ajaanbaahu In that case (actually in almost all cases) you should profile your code to see where it spends most of the time. Just call it with `python -m cProfile script_name.py`. I would guess most time will be spent in the `word_tokenize` function. Not sure if ctypes will help you there, but I don't have any experience with them, so...